# Docker cannot ping within container

Tags: docker

I am running into a weird issue with docker where I can't ping anything within a docker container. I don't think it is a dns issue because I am able to resolve the ip address. However, I am getting 100% packet loss. This could also be related to VPN settings.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated**

Running container with: docker run -it -v C:/git/project/:/container/directory node /bin/bash

Within container: ping www.google.com

Output: PING www.google.com (172.217.6.4): 56 data bytes

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And include some basic diagnostics...can you ping your host at the address of the docker bridge (the default gateway inside the container)? Can you ping an address on your host's primary interface? What about your local network?

Comment: Yes, I am able to ping host. I am also using my companies network

Answer (score -2):

Just ran into this issue and resolved it by making sure `DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS` is empty in `/etc/sysconfig/docker-network`.